# How to export comments?

Tags: 7, nodes, migrations, comments, importing-exporting

I have two Drupal website setups. One is development and another one is live. In my live setup lot of comments are there. I want to export all comments and import to development setup.
How can I do that?

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you working with?

Comment: using drupal 7.i am struggling with this in lot of days.

Comment: either use migrate module or use features module

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to migrate content is the [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module, in the module page you can find many Case studies with code inside and in the [documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/node/415260) you will find all the information that you need.

Inside the Migrate module folder you can find the Beer.inc file, which is an example of how you can do simple mappings. For more complicated migrations you can look into Wine.inc.